# JSON php parsing trouble

Tags: php, json

I am trying to loop through a list of urls that have json to extract and store the data for later. Below is the code I am trying to run on a windows php machine, when I run it on a mac it works just fine but when ran on windows I get the below error

Notice: Trying to get property 'included' of non-object in D:\sstkjson.php on line 23
Data received
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'included' of non-object in D:\sstkjson.php on line 23

```
<?php

$urllist = file("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blah/gistfile1.txt");
$newids = [];

foreach ($urllist as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($response);

    if ($curl_errno > 0) {
        echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
    } else {
        echo "Data received\n";
    }

    if($json->included) {
        foreach ($json->included as $id) {
            $newids[] = $id->id;
        }
    }

    file_put_contents("ids.txt", implode(PHP_EOL,$newids));
}

?>
```

Comment: `json_decode()` is failing for some reason.

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blah/gistfile1.txt this url not found can you share url so i can debug issue

Comment: Try `var_dump($response)` to see what you're getting.

Comment: You should check `$curl_errno` *before* you try to use `$response`.

Comment: Here is a link to the actual file [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tcope25/c22ff05f1c371985cf9d25652c28ea11/raw/59ef3e4a1c1852ecb09188a4524961f3df81f67c/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your request is not getting any response so the issue is coming, to prevent notice you can write code like below.

```
<?php

$urllist = file("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blah/gistfile1.txt");
$newids = [];

foreach ($urllist as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($response);

    if ($curl_errno > 0) {
        echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
    } else {
        echo "Data received\n";

         if(!empty($json) && !empty($json->included)) {
              foreach ($json->included as $id) {
                   $newids[] = $id->id;
              }
         }

         file_put_contents("ids.txt", implode(PHP_EOL,$newids));

    }

}
```

?>

Comment: This does not throw an error but doesnt return any data now though.. here is the link to the correct txt file [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tcope25/c22ff05f1c371985cf9d25652c28ea11/raw/59ef3e4a1c1852ecb09188a4524961f3df81f67c/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: @johncsmith427 this example is working for me perfectly in my windows... I think Shutterstock blocked your ip so its not returning any data

Comment: @johncsmith427  you can use proxy in windows to get data and also maintain some time from 2 request using sleep function.